# Was the T-1000 dressed at all?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

> The T-1000 snuck up on the cop and stabbed him, **mimicking his clothing** and taking his gun.

A quote from [the wiki](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-1000_(Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day)#Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day). So he wasn't actually wearing real clothes?

Comment: The T-1000 was a nudist at home. He only wore clothes out in public.

Comment: Why is it even a confusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, it wasn't

There are *many* occasions in the film where we see that the T-1000's "clothes" are just extensions of its liquid metal body. Note that I don't *think* any of these videos contain spoilers, but then I've seen this movie so many times that I have no idea what counts as a spoiler for it anymore:

Comment: I think when a film is 26 years old there's no need to worry about spoilers.

Comment: @Tim [Stop making me feel old, god](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLAL5.gif)